# Delete Rows in apache spark using java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

Need to delete second row in that dataset i am new to apache spark can anyone help me to resolve.
below is the code:

```
  public class DeleteRow {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutils");
          JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("JoinFunctions").setMaster("local[*]"));
          SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
          SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JavaTokenizerExample").getOrCreate();

          List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create(1,"Hi I heard about Spark"),
            RowFactory.create(2,"I wish Java could use case classes"),
            RowFactory.create(3,"Logistic,regression,models,are,neat"));

          StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
            new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,
              Metadata.empty()),
          new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false,
            Metadata.empty()) });

            String ins  = data.get(1).toString();
            System.out.println(ins);



          Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
        sentenceDataFrame.drop(data.get(1).toString());
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to define the row you are removing? Do you want all elements to be the same as the chosen row? do you want to do it by some indexing? all rows that match some parameter?

Comment: Above examples i want to remove second row ("I wish Java could use case classes")

Comment: so you want indexing? i.e. give each row an id and remove by that id? Giving each row a consecutive id (0,1,2) can be costly. Would a hash (and the risk of removing more than one) be good enough?

Comment: Do you need all rows except 2nd row and are all labels unique?

Comment: Yes i want all rows except 2nd row thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a FilterFunction.

I wrote a JUnit Test to help you out.

```
@Test
public void sampleDeleteRowTest() throws Exception {
    List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create(1, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
            RowFactory.create(2, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
            RowFactory.create(3, "Logistic,regression,models,are,neat"));

    StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("label", DataTypes.IntegerType, false,
                    Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("sentence", DataTypes.StringType, false,
                    Metadata.empty())});

    String ins = data.get(1).toString();
    System.out.println(ins);


    Dataset<Row> sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);
    long size = sentenceDataFrame.count();

    assertTrue("SentenceDataFrame Size = " + sentenceDataFrame.count(), size == 3);

    sentenceDataFrame = sentenceDataFrame.filter(new FilterFunction<Row>() {
        @Override
        public boolean call(Row row) throws Exception {
            Integer label = row.getInt(0);
            return label != 2;
        }
    });

    size = sentenceDataFrame.count();

    assertTrue("SentenceDataFrame Size = " + sentenceDataFrame.count(), size == 2);
}
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#filter(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FilterFunction.html

Alternatively, you can use a Lambda function to achieve the same desired result:

```
sentenceDataFrame = sentenceDataFrame.filter((FilterFunction<Row>) r -> (r).getInt(0) != 2);
```